# Including a color scheme when passing color as a dict Altair

Tags: json, schema, altair, vega

How do I add a color scheme to the first condition (instead of 'red')?

The code below works as intended. I have had to write in dictionary form for it to work:

```
cutoff = 10
color_data = 'RME' #(RME is a column within the dataset)
condition_test = {
    'condition': [
        {'test': f'{selection.name} && datum.{color_data} < {cutoff}', 'value': 'red'},
        {'test': f'{selection.name} && datum.{color_data} >= {cutoff}', 'value': 'black'}
    ],
    'value': 'lightgray'
}
```

My attempts at adding the color scheme:

```
condition_test = {
    'condition': [
        {'test': f'{selection.name} && datum.{color_data} < {cutoff}', 'field': color_data + ':Q','scale': {'scheme': 'redpurple', 'domain' : [0, cutoff]}, 'legend': None},
        {'test': f'{selection.name} && datum.{color_data} >= {cutoff}', 'value': 'black'}
    ],
    'value': 'lightgray'
}
```

(above leads to SchemaValidationError)

Below is a toy example that works (but does not include the color scheme that I'm after):

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

# Load example data
source = data.cars()

# Define the selection
my_selection = alt.selection_interval(encodings=['x'])

cutoff = 100

base = scatter = alt.Chart(source).mark_point().encode(
    x='Horsepower:Q',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon:Q',
    color=alt.ColorValue('lightgray'))

# Create the scatter plot with color encoding
scatter = alt.Chart(source).mark_point().encode(
    x='Horsepower:Q',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon:Q',
    color = {
    'condition': [
        {'test': f'{my_selection.name} && datum.Horsepower < {cutoff}', 'value': 'red'},
        {'test': f'{my_selection.name} && datum.Horsepower >= {cutoff}', 'value': 'black'}
    ],
    'value': 'lightgray'
}
).add_selection(my_selection)

# Apply the interval selection to the scatter plot
scatter = scatter.transform_filter(my_selection)

# Show the scatter plot
base + scatter
```

Thanks